# Cual es la diferencia entre ASP.NET Web Site y Web Application en Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Necesito hacer un proyecto en `asp.net` con `web forms`, realmente soy nuevo en `asp.net` y a la hora de crear el proyecto he visto tutoriales en que utilizan las dos variantes o crean un `WebSite` o crean un `WebApplication`. Quisiera saber cual es la diferencia para saber cual es la que mas me conviene.
Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Web Site** es un tipo de proyecto independiente no relacionado a Visual Studio. Osea si renombras un archivo que tiene referencia en otro archivo, esa referencia no se actualizara. Por ejemplo referencia la de una clase en una vista. Si renombras la clase, no se actualizara en tu vista. Por decirlo asi, Visual Studio no tiene control del mismo.

Mientras que **Web Application** es un tipo de proyecto especial de Visual Studio donde si esta al tanto de los cambios que haces en los archivos. Si renombras una clase, esta se actualizara en todos los jugares donde Visual Studio tenga referencia de ella. Esto hace mas facil de manejar. Este tipo de proyecto tambien, a diferencia de WebSite, compila todo el codigo en una sola `dll` lo que lo hace mas organizado que el WebSite y menos pesado.

Comment: Eso me aclara bastante las cosas, muchas gracias.

Comment: Para complementar un poco más la información de Einer, En los Web Site cada de unas de las paginas .aspx representa una dll. Esto trae un mayor uso de la memoria ya que al ser dll independientes, esta se cargan de forma dinámica.